# How can I change the startup sound in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
sudo cp desktop-login.ogg desktop-login.ogg.old
sudo cp ~/Downloads/dekstop-login.ogg .
```

...where the `ogg` file in the `Downloads` directory is the new startup song.

This script has successfully replaced the old file and I can see and play the new `ogg` file in the `stereo` directory, but I can't hear anything at startup.

Are there any other methods?

Comment: Did you make sure that the script didn't disable the sound at startup? http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-startup-login-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html

Comment: It did not. The sound works just fine, both in the login screen and while logged in. The startup sound doesn't play though.

Comment: Are you logging in as guest or an account? If account, does it play when logging in as guest?

Comment: Also, try to delete the .dconf in home folder and start over.

Comment: Deleting the .gconf seems to have solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the .dconf in home folder and start over.

Comment: That's why I converted it to an answer - so he can accept the answer as definitive. Don't understand the problem.